# Create a view that displays only the fields from the most recent user node

Tags: users, views, entities

To specify, I want the view to only apply to one single node and not all other nodes and only pull fields from that one particular node that was last created. 
As of now the view displays all the nodes and their fields with a pager, I just want it to load content from the last node created by that user.

Can anyone suggest?

Comment: use views contextual filters.

Answer (score 1):

- Add a contextual filter for user
- Set pager to "none" and "number of items to display" to "1".
- Set a sort criteria to sort by date, descending.